# LOGINs on new MASTER for restored database

Tags: azure-synapse

I have a new logical server on which I will be restoring an existing Azure SQL Data Warehouse database from a different logical server.

I've reviewed https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-restore-database-portal but need to understand how the LOGINs are handled on the new MASTER database.  USERs exist on the database to be restored and they relate to LOGINs on the old MASTER database.

Do the LOGINs have to be manually CREATEd on the new MASTER before the restore occurs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logins have to be created on the MASTER of the new logical server. This can happen anytime before you re-create the users in the DW. After you have the Logins created, you then need to drop and re-create the users in the DW that you restored to the new logical server. That will associate your users in the DW with the logins in master.

If you have AAD integration with your on-premises AD in place and enabled for your DW, these steps are not needed.